# Does daily package version limit count failed attempts?

Tags: salesforcedx, limits, package

Do failed attempts to create unlocked packages count against an org's daily package version creation limit?

Comment: Yes, it counts failed attempts as well in the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure with the answer, but you can test it yourself.
First run this command in terminal:

```
sfdx force:limits:api:display
```

Note the current **Package2VersionCreates** Remaining integer.

Then try to create unlocked package with failed status and run the command again.

UPDATE: It also would be kind of you if you post your result here in comments to show others.
It's better to see it yourself.

Comment: I was able to confirm that it counts failed attempts in the limits. I'm not exactly sure if deployment has to reach a certain stage, e.g. 'Queued', 'InProgress' before counting against the limit. All my failing deployments reached the 'InProgress' stage.